# Scoring runs in a single ball

Tags: cricket, officiating

If a batsman hits a ball and the players keep running after 4 runs scored still the ball not reached the boundary. No over throw is considered. Whether all the runs will be included in batsman individual score?

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. I notice you are using two accounts. For more information about merging these accounts, refer [here](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean the batsman hits it, it goes over the boundary for 4 runs, and they keep running? In that case, no further runs are counted (bar any penalties awarded) as the ball is dead once it crosses the boundary - see [Law 23 - Dead Ball](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-23-dead-ball/).

In the event that the batsmen manage to run more than 4 runs before the ball crosses the boundary, the runs ran will count, so the batsmen get the larger number of runs - see [Law 19 - Boundaries](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-19-boundaries/).

Finally, if the ball fails to cross the boundary, the batsmen are entitled to continue running until they choose to stop, or "Lost ball" is called. See [Law 18 - Scoring Runs](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-18-scoring-runs/) and  [Law 20 - Lost Ball](http://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-20-lost-ball/).

Answer (score 0):

As @truedub says they score any runs that are run prior to the ball crossing the boundary.

However from the point of view of recording the number of 4 or 6 hit they only count the cases where the ball crosses the boundary they dont count all run 4 and 6.

Answer (score -3):

I'm sure the batsman is allowed to run as long as he desires if the ball is not over the boundary line. The question is if the batsman run 6 times, will he be entitled as hitting a sixer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to that already covered by the second paragraph of TrueDub's answer.